# How can I use a dictionary to store unique items?

Tags: excel, vba

I have read through the documentation but the main thing I am seeing is `exists` which I believe would work great if I didn't need to preserve the order of the keys. Essentially each index/record of the dictionary makes a unique identifier. So individual keys could be the same as long as the complete line is unique.

```
Dim d
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
y = 0
For i = 2 To Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  'some code to check values uniqueness
  d.Add "Index", y
  d.Add "Date", Cells(i, 3)
  d.Add "FirstName", Cells(i, 6)
  d.Add "LastName", Cells(i, 7)
  y = y + 1
Next i
```

Dictionary would look like this:

```txt
Index         1
Date          29/12/2021
FirstName     John
LastName      Smith
```

So using exists wouldn't work as I could have multiple firstnames called John, I thought about nested exists but I don't think that would work either.

Guess the main question is a dictionary the best way to do this?
I guess all of this is just a fancy way of removing duplicates in a list, would I be better off using `RemoveDuplicates` on a Range?

Comment: Yes to your last question.

Comment: You could concatenate all the values and use the concatenated value as the key.  You don't tell us anything about where the data is coming from though (or what you need to do with it later), so it's difficult to be more specific or to know what might be the "best" approach

Comment: Dictionaries do not store unique items.  They store items based on a unique Key.  Unique keys can have the same items.  If you need a unique list then just use the keys of a dictionary to store your information and add Item as the count of the dictionary.  This will give you unique items plus the order in which they were added to the dictionary.  Alternatively, take a look at the ArrayList object.  This object as a 'COntains' method so that you can ensure that you only include unique items and items are reference by index (the order in which items are added to the array list).

Answer (score 0):

### Removing Duplicates Using `RemoveDuplicates`

- This removes the records if the values in the same row of columns 3, 6, and 7 are duplicates i.e. are already found in previous rows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDupes()
    
    Dim Cols As Variant: Cols = VBA.Array(3, 6, 7)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    rg.RemoveDuplicates (Cols), xlYes

End Sub
```